# Can't use @string notation to define <intent-filter> in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

My BroadcastReceiver never gets called when I use "@string/action_name" to define the intent filter action. If I copy/paste the corresponding string from strings.xml into AndroidManifest.xml, then it works perfectly!

**Non** working example from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ServerUpdateReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="@string/ACTION_INFORM_USER_SERVER_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Working example from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".ServerUpdateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.franklinharper.intent.action.ACTION_INFORM_USER_SERVER_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Just for completeness, strings.xml contains the following line:

```
<string name="ACTION_INFORM_USER_SERVER_UPDATE">com.franklinharper.intent.action.ACTION_INFORM_USER_SERVER_UPDATE</string>
```

Comment: This kind of things make me cry. I've wasted almost 1 hour trying to figure out why my `BroadcastReceiver` didn't trigger. Using an string resource makes sense because you have everything in one place and you avoid duplicated constants. Now imagine someone comes and changes the action string on the Manifest but not in the other places... Pathetic.

Comment: That's weird, thanks for the quesiton

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [spec](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html), there is no way to configure an action with a resource identifier. It has to be a simple string, perhaps to avoid requiring the Android Intent dispatch system to open your APK to figure out what the filter is for.

Comment: If I'm understanding you, and the documentation, correctly the "@string/name" syntax isn't being interpreted in this case. This is rather confusing because the ADT plugin is perfectly happy to do autocompletion. What I was trying to do was have one unique action name that was referred to by the Code and the manifest. But this doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: It's sad, as I wanted to make everything pretty constant, but it's ok.